# Using OnTouchListener to redraw GLRenderered Square?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, ontouchlistener

My program is to have a white square appear and travel on the z a xis when the screen is touched.

My goal and problem is that I also want this to happen again when the screen is touched again and again.

for some reason adding invalidate(); after square.draw doesn't work. I've also tried to create a thread in the activity class to lock and unlock the canvas. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing and if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

Here is my GLRendering Class in my Activity Class

```
public class GL1Activity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

GLSurfaceView ourSurface;
float x,y;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    ourSurface = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    ourSurface.setOnTouchListener(this);
    x=0;
    y=0;
    ourSurface.setRenderer(new GL1Renderer()); //links to GL1Renderer
    setContentView(ourSurface);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    ourSurface.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    ourSurface.onResume();

    }


@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    x = event.getX();
    y = event.getY();

    return false;
} 

public class GL1Renderer implements Renderer {

    private GL1Square square;
    float zoomz;
    public GL1Renderer (){
        square = new GL1Square();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig eglconfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);
    gl.glClearColor(.1f, .1f, .1f, 1); //painting background
    gl.glClearDepthf(1f);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, -5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0);
        if (x != 0 && y != 0){  
        gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, zoomz);
        if (zoomz < 50) {
            zoomz-=.1;      
        }
        if (zoomz > 50){
            zoomz = 0;
        }
        square.draw(gl);

        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        float ratio = (float) width/height;
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, 25); 
        }
    }
```

And this is Square code;

```
public class GL1Square {

private float vertices[] = {
        -1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f,
};
private short[] pIndex = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3};

private ShortBuffer pBuff;

private FloatBuffer vertBuff;

public GL1Square(){
    ByteBuffer bBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    bBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertBuff = bBuff.asFloatBuffer();
    vertBuff.put(vertices);
    vertBuff.position(0);

    ByteBuffer pbBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(pIndex.length * 2);
    pbBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    pBuff = pbBuff.asShortBuffer();
    pBuff.put(pIndex);
    pBuff.position(0);
}

public void draw(GL10 gl){
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_FRONT);
    gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertBuff);
    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, pIndex.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, pBuff);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to call the onDrawFrame() from your Activity class...?
This would well from my understanding anyway would redraw the frame.